# How to feed FirebaseInstanceID Token to observer on NodeJS server from Android application?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send notifications to my android app. 
I have a NodeJS backend with Firesbase as my DB and my client is an Android app.

This is my observer on my NodeJS:

```
var observer = db.collection(‘bookings’)
 .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
   querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach(change => {
     if (change.type === ‘added’) {
       // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
       var registrationToken = ‘YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN’; //can't find this
       // See documentation on defining a message payload.
       var message = {
         data: {
           score: ‘850’,
           time: ‘2:45’
         },
         token: registrationToken
       };
       // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
       // registration token.
       admin.messaging().send(message)
         .then((response) => {
           // Response is a message ID string.
           console.log(‘Successfully sent message:’, response);
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.log(‘Error sending message:’, error);
         });
       console.log(‘New booking: ’, change.doc.data());
     }
     else if (change.type === ‘modified’) {
       console.log(‘Modified booking: ’, change.doc.data());
     }
     else if (change.type === ‘removed’) {
       console.log(‘Removed booking: ’, change.doc.data());
     }
   });
 });
```

I am unable to figured out how to persist the FirebaseInstanceID Token somewhere in the server or DB?